# How to set the "end" of an array of structs

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, sentinel

I would like to set the equivalent of a `\0` to the end of an array of structs so I know when it ends.

So far I am trying to do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char * id;
    char * date;
} ROW;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE * fp = fopen("test100k.csv", "r");
    ROW * rows = malloc(sizeof(row) * 10000);
    int row_num = 0;
    ROW row;
    char buffer[255];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {  
        // some logic to set the object
        rows[row_num++] = row;
    }

    rows[row_num] =  NULL; // how to do this?

}
```

What would be the proper way to "end" the array of rows?

Comment: @melpomene updated with that def.

Comment: Why do you need to "end" the array? You already know how big it is: `row_num`.

Comment: @melpomene this would be for another loop I would have after (not shown) where I process it a bit.

Comment: Why can't this other loop use `row_num`?

Comment: @melpomene it could, I'm just trying to figure out how to set the end of an array.

Comment: There is nothing to set.

Comment: In this particular case you could set both fields to NULL.  It's probably best however to just keep track of the size.

Comment: That way if you pass `rows` to another function and want to do `size_t n = 0; while (rows[n].id != NULL) { ... }` you can. You are using the `.id` field as a *sentinel*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin We don't know if `id = NULL` can't occur in normal rows. *`// some logic to set the object`* is not shown. Also, if you can pass `rows`, you can pass `row_num`.

Comment: (Your are right! That was presuming it was set `NULL` as @dbush discussed in the comment above or in my comment below the answer below. It must me explicitly set `NULL` before you can use it that way. No we don't need to debate whether `memset (..., 0, ...)` and setting the `.id` pointer `NULL` differ.)

Comment: OT:  When calling `fopen()` and/or `malloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, (==NULL) then call `perror( "..,. failed" );` then cleanup and exit the program.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`  Since the parameters: `argc` and `argv[]` are not used, the compiler will output two warnings messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to defined a constant which serves as sentinel by the unique value(s) of it's member(s):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char * id;
    char * date;
} ROW;

/* Initialising the ROW's members below to a literal could lead to 
   ambiguities, as the compiler is free to merge the same literal 
   appearing more then once into only one instance in memory. 
   Whereas initialising the members to the struct's address itself 
   guarantees the uniqueness of the address stored.
   (Just do not ever dereference it, at least not without casting it 
   back to the type ROW.) */

const ROW STOPPER_ROW = {(char*)&STOPPER_ROW, (char*)&STOPPER_ROW};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...

    ROW * rows = malloc(10000 * sizeof *rows);
    size_t row_num = 0;
    ...

    while(NULL != fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) && 
          10000 > row_num) {    
        // some logic to set the object
        rows[row_num++] = row;
    }

    rows[row_num] = STOPPER_ROW;

    row_num = 0;
    /* Comparing only one member below in fact would do. */
    while (rows[row_num].id != STOPPER_ROW.id && 
           rows[row_num].date != STOPPER_ROW.date)
    {
        /* Use rows[row_num] here */
        ++row_num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uniqueness is not the property that is required here. There is no guarantee that all possible addresses can't represent a valid id and date.

Answer (score 0):

These are the standard approaches:

- Add a counter variable that will indicate the last valid index.
- Store rows by reference rather than by value. I.e., allocate a space for each row and store a pointer to it in the array instead of storing the row itself. The row is invalid if the pointer is null.
- If there is a known invalid value for a row, initialize all the array cells to this value. A cell with invalid value will indicate end of valid items.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use memset:

```
memset(&rows[row_num], NULL, sizeof(ROW));
```

Comment: The second argument to `memset` is a byte value. You cannot pass `NULL` here.

Comment: `memset(&rows[row_num], 0, sizeof(ROW));` ??

Comment: Even if `NULL` is corrected to `0`, the C standard does not guarantee that all zero bits represents a null pointer.